# Safest anti-static wrist strap band attachment point

Tags: security, hardware-failure, electric-shock

It is commonly suggested for an anti-static wrist strap band to be attached to the ground of an electrical outlet (plugged in PSU) and while I am aware of the resistors that wrist strap bands have to protect from an electrical outlet failure, I am not sure if using the ground of the electrical outlet is a necessity as it still seems a bit risky. I saw the suggestion of attaching it to an uncoated piece of metal, such as the case. Is there actually an alternative, working way other than that of the electrical outlet/plugged in PSU or the only true ground (that is effective) is the one of the electrical outlet?

Comment: Just get a decent strap (https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/pomona-electronics/6081/745116) and connect the strap to a true ground (not painted metal).

Comment: *"Is there actually an alternative ..."* -- Yes, you could use techniques similar to grounding a roof TV/radio antenna/aerial.  But you need to be sure that the "ground" used is at or a lower potential than the house's electrical wiring. Or get an electrician to verify the grounding of the outlets(s), and connect the strap the easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a decent wrist strap.

Here is one such strap but you can choose your own also.

[Wrist strap possibilty](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/pomona-electronics/6081/745116)

The wrist strap should be connected to a true ground (the earth ground of a common 2 wire plus ground electrical outlet).  I have such outlets on my own bench. Make sure the metal is not painted, rusted or have any other coating. Just bare metal.

Here is a decent article on why and how to use a wrist strap.

[Using a Wrist Strap](https://www.wepc.com/how-to/properly-use-anti-static-wrist-strap/)

> What Is An Anti Static Wrist Strap? You have probably heard or even
> seen technicians wearing anti-static wrist straps when building
> computers in video tutorials and even from your trusted computer shop
> and repair center. This should be enough to give you a hint as to why
> they are needed when building a computer.
>
> To keep it simple, an anti-static wrist strap is used to make sure
> that the voltage difference in your body and the computer is balanced
> out. By grounding your body with an anti-static wrist strap, any
> excess static charge in your body will be dissipated right away.

Comment: Worth pointing out that an "uncoated piece of metal, such as the case" isn't true ground.  Now does it discharge enough of the static charge to be safe enough to work on your hardware, it might, but are you willing to risk hardware that is hundreds of dollars to avoid spending $10-15 on a wrist strap and grounding post necessary to be truly grounded?

Comment: @Ramhound - If your mains is correctly earthed, the the case is also correctly earthed. if you live somewhere that proper earthing is not compulsory, ymmv.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I have worked with a lot of electronics, I have seen an ESD event first hand, it's cool to see but horrible to deal with the aftermath.  I take it seriously.

Comment: @Ramhound - I've seen hundreds, I used to work electronics/media maintenance in retail, sometimes 25 stores a day, checking, upgrading devices & server maintenance. Some days you'd get zapped by every damn fixture in every store… still never killed a device. Sensibly grounding as you open the case… I live in a territory where earth is compulsory, & it works.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I have seen literally sparks fly when proper grounding wasn't used.  So i might be a freak about it but I am seen the aftermath of improper grounding.

Comment: @Ramhound - You must live in the US :p It just doesn't happen here, everything is properly earthed, by law. As I say, I've seen & felt many zaps, but the earthing prevents the device getting it, only the engineer jumps halfway back across the room at first touch. We also, incidentally, specifically differentiate between the concepts of 'earth' & 'ground'. Ground is a signal ground [or 'common'], earth is a real physical connection back to a spike in the soil.

Answer (score 1):

If the PSU is plugged in and is not painted, the PSU's case should provide a good ground. (Scratch the alligator clip over the metal to chew through any oxide layer.) Outlet ground is still the best (assuming your outlet is wired correctly); this is the connection your appliances use to protect you from internal short circuits.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about it too much. Unless you get sparks off everything you touch in the building, then just leaving the device plugged to properly earthed mains, with the plug switched off, then touching the main metal structure as you open it should be plenty good enough.

I haven't worn a wrist strap in 40 years & I've not zapped anything yet.

Obviously, don't go rubbing the cat with a ballon or an amber rod, or run up & down a nylon carpet in plastic-soled shoes, but after that, 'reasonable precautions' are just that - reasonable.

Also worth pointing out that not all territories have good electrical regulations with compulsory earth [I'm looking right at you, US of A, with a sideways glance at half the EU too ;) If you live in such a territory, then you need to make certain your earth is actually earthed.